# fileno, F_LOCK and F_ULOCK become undeclared and unavailable when I add std=c99 flag to gcc

Tags: c, gcc, c99

I have these headers in a c code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

Everything compiled fine until I added -std=c99 flag to gcc command (to enable [restrict](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13825)). And this triggered the following errors.

> warning: implicit declaration of
>   function `fileno`
>
> error: `F_LOCK` undeclared (first use
>   in this function)
>   error: (Each undeclared identifier is
>   reported only once            error:
>   for each function it appears in.)
>   error: `F_ULOCK` undeclared (first use
>   in this function

Any ideas to workaround these errors/warnings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to tell the headers that you want the POSIX extensions.  These days, I use:

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
#else
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#endif /* __STDC_VERSION__ */
```

If I'm compiling with `-std=c89`, it gives the correct POSIX version; if you compile with `-std=c89`, it gives the correct POSIX version.  I use this on Solaris 9 and 10, MacOS X (10.4.x, 10.5.x), HP-UX 11.x, Linux (RHEL4 and 5, SuSE 9 and 10) and AIX 5.x and 6.x - AFAICR, without problems so far.

This stanza should appear before any system headers are included (in your own header, or in each source file), or you need to achieve the same effect with `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600` on the compiler command line, or some other similar mechanism.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
-std=gnu99
```

to enable all extensions and still use the C99 language enhancements.

Answer (score 1):

You might try -D_BSD_SOURCE to enable BSD-isms or -D_SVID_SOURCE to enable System-V isms

Comment: Use `-D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE` on MacOS X; `-D__EXTENSIONS__` on Solaris; `-D_GNU_SOURCE` on Linux; and the list continues (not sure what the equivalents are on HP-UX and AIX, but they exist, almost certainly).